# Mac's time keeps changing back 15 days

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, time

I have a 13-inch, 2019 MacBook Air. The time keeps changing back 15 days every time the computer sleeps, when I log back in, or when a restart happens. I have set the clock to sync automatically but the time keeps jumping back 15 days from today. I have done a PRAM/SMC reset already but it does not seem to help. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Currently, I am on Sonoma 14.1.1

Even if I put in the date without the sync i.e. manually with the time sync off, it will still move back to the old time every time it wakes up.

Comment: What if you DON'T set the clock to a time server? Also, what OS version, and which time server are you using? And where are you?

Comment: The time was the same 15 days ago ! are you saying the date changes

Comment: Apologies, i have added the details now.

Comment: Do you have any software installed that might be causing this? Does the problem occur in Safe Boot mode, or in a brand new user account? Does it keep going back an extra 15 days every time? (ie. if you don't reset it.) This is very weird. It needs some in-depth looking at, and as much detail as you can give us.

Comment: I dont install anything on this machine as i use it all the time to work. So here is what happens, this happens even in safe mode. So what exactly happens is the computer starts up with a date that is 15 days earlier. I wrote a cronjob in the terminal which updates the time forcefully `sntp -sS time.apple.com / sudo sntp -sS in.pool.ntp.org` .  once the time is updated there is no other errors. But everytime the computer sleeps it will go back to a date and time which is 15 days older than the current time. for example if its 23rd nov 1:55 pm IST it will go to 9th nov 2:55 AM

Answer (score 1):

One day my laptop accidently ran out of battery completely and was dead. It was dead overnight and in the morning when i plugged the battery back up and it started up the time issue got resolved by itself. So i guess the hardware clock might have got reset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The following fixed it for me.

`sudo mv /var/db/timed/com.apple.timed.plist ~/Destop ; sudo reboot`

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253909330?sortBy=best